# apply powershell script to multiple xml files

Tags: xml, csv, powershell

I have a Powershell script that queries an xml document and outputs the results to a csv file. The script works but I need to apply it to multiple xml files in a folder and output the combined results to a csv. How can this script be modified to do this? Thanks

```
$xml = [XML](Get-Content D:demo\test.xml) #load xml document

#this finds file names of yearbook picks
$picks = $xml.Client.Order.Ordered_Items.Ordered_Item |
    Where-Object { $_.Description -eq 'yearbook Luster Print' } |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Images.Image_Name }


# this finds the Album
$album = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Album_ID").InnerText -split '_'

$results = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      Last= $album[0]
      First= $album[1]
      Code= $album[2]
      Pick1= $picks[0]
      Pick2= $picks[1]
    }

#output CSV File
$results | Export-Csv -path D:\demo\myoutput.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the XML files and append them to your output file:

```
# Get all XML files
$items = Get-ChildItem *.xml

# Loop over them and append them to the document
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $xml = [XML](Get-Content $item) #load xml document

    #this finds file names of yearbook picks
    $picks = $xml.Client.Order.Ordered_Items.Ordered_Item |
        Where-Object { $_.Description -eq 'yearbook Luster Print' } |
            ForEach-Object { $_.Images.Image_Name }

    # this finds the Album
    $album = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Album_ID").InnerText -split '_'

    $results = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
          Last= $album[0]
          First= $album[1]
          Code= $album[2]
          Pick1= $picks[0]
          Pick2= $picks[1]
        }

    # Append to CSV File
    $results | Export-Csv -path D:\demo\myoutput.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```